# Display text using Lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda, interface

Job at hand:-

Write a main method.

- ```
       Invoke the above static method.
  ```
- ```
       Using that reference invoke the default method getInput.
  ```
- ```
       Store that String in a variable.
  ```
- ```
       Invoke the displayText method by passing this String as parameter.
  ```
- ```
       The output should be as shown in the sample data below.
  ```

  Input: Watson

  Expected Output: Welcome Watson

Till now I have written the following code and its working also but my evaluation fails. Is there any other way to fulfill all the requirements given in the question.

```
Main.java
    1 public class Main implements DisplayText
    2 {
    3     public static void main(String args[])
    4     {
    5         Main obj = new Main();
    6         obj.welcomeMessage();
    7         //String name=obj.getInput();
    8         //obj.displayText(name);
    9     }
   10     public static DisplayText welcomeMessage()
   11     {
   12         DisplayText ref = (String str) -> {
   13             System.out.println("Welcome "+str);
   14         };
   15         ref.displayText(ref.getInput());
   16         return ref;
   17     }
   18     public void displayText(String text)
   19     {
   20         System.out.println(text);
   21     }
   22 }

DisplayText.java
    1 import java.util.*;
    2 public interface DisplayText
    3 {
    4     public void displayText(String text);
    5     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    6     public default String getInput()
    7     {
    8         String message = sc.nextLine();
    9         return message;
   10     }
   11     
   12 }
```

Comment: If you have cases that fail, you should probably find out why they fail before asking a question. You can use the debugger or just simple print statements to follow what the code is doing and whether it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the problem says is that the `DisplayText` interface is a "Functional interface" and you have to annotate it as such. There's no need to make Main class to implement that interface, nor to define the `Scanner` as interface member.
I would implement the solution in this way:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

@FunctionalInterface
interface DisplayText {
    void displayText(String text);
    
    public default String getInput()
    {
        System.out.print("Your name: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
}

public class Main {

     public static void main(String... args) {
        welcomeMessage();
     }
     
    public static void welcomeMessage()
    {
        DisplayText ref = (String str) -> System.out.println("Welcome "+str);
         
        ref.displayText(ref.getInput());
     }
}
```

Here is the output I got:

```
D:\Marco\workspace>javac Main.java

D:\Marco\workspace>java Main
Your name: Watson
Welcome Watson
```